# Keep getting the wrong output when writing passing a word through a function

Tags: python

I'm writing a code where I ask the user for input through a function. When the beginning index of the word is capital I want it to output "True". When the beginning index of the word is lowercase I want it to print "False". Every time I input a word thats lowercase, I still get the output "True."

Here is the code that I have written:

```
def printWord():
    user = input("Please enter a word here: " )
    
    if user[0].upper():
        print("True")
        
    elif user[0].lower(): 
        print("False")

printWord()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `isupper()/islower()` methods. `upper()` will convert that charcter/string to uppercase.

```
def printWord():
    user = input("Please enter a word here: " )
    
    if user[0].isupper():
        print("True")
        
    elif user[0].islower(): 
        print("False")

printWord()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isupper()`

```py
>>> "a".upper()
'A'
>>> "A".upper()
'A'
>>> "a".isupper()
False
>>> "A".isupper()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

`"myword".upper()` -> `MYWORD`

`"myword".isupper()` -> `False`

`"MYWORD".isupper()` -> `True`

`.upper()` **transforms** a string to uppercase, `.isupper()` **checks**  whether a string is uppercase.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_upper.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isupper.asp

Your code works when you replace `.upper()` and `.lower()` with `.usupper()` and `.islower()`.